# table design or div design, confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

have the following screen design for my demo application.
Should this design be done using a `<DIV>` or a `<TABLE>`?

Note: when you click on the data row it expands (accordion like) and shows description row where you can see some description about the row as a single column which spans across the width of the table.

The menu works when user clicks on an image given in that column.

I know that a table is used only to represent tabular data.
I have the menu in last column as well as an accordion like hidden row for each data row showing the description when user clicks on the data row.
So, I am not sure whether it can be considered as part of a tabular data.

This is related to fulfilling the following web-guideline:
http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20140311/complete-diff.html#H51

The data is going to be text apart from the menu. Each menu link performs different functionality. The accordion row is also text mostly.

Please advise here.
Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: gor for bootstrap css, design responsive sites using div

Comment: @FrebinFrancis please see my edit, added web-guideline link: http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20140311/complete-diff.html#H51 which i intend to satisfy.

Comment: Best explanation : - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html?rq=1

Comment: @MukeshPrajapat lol, you serious?

Comment: I would use div because it is normally a lot more flexible than tables.

Comment: "Should this design be done using a `<DIV>` or a `<TABLE>`" — It's hard to say since you haven't told us very much about the data you are dealing with. I'd be tempted to suggest that it might be a job for a `<dl>` but there really isn't enough information to say for sure.

Comment: @Quentin The data is going to be text apart from the menu. Each menu link performs different functionality. The accordion row is also text mostly.

Comment: "text" isn't very descriptive. The point of HTML is to describe the structure and semantics of text. It's hard to tell what the semantics that should be described are without real context.